# Any +4 digit zip code API's available for CRM 2015?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Currently, I'm trying to implement a requirement that when a user enters an address with a 5- digit zip-code, the rest(+4 zip-code) auto-populate.

Example: John(sales-man), is entering a new mailing address for James(a new client) into the system. Upon filling out  James mailing address, he types in the first 5-digits of the zip-code. He doesn't remember the last four, I'll like to have the system suggest possible last 4-digit that correspond to the first 5-digit of the zip-code. This is important for any out-going mail.

Any suggestions, would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

PS: Presently, I'm using all the system fields for the address. CRM-Online 2015.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use autocomplete functionality that became available - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607648.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: That's a possible solution, but won't be efficient if I have to write a suggested +4 zip-code for every zip-code in America.

Comment: You can store it in Xml/Json format in webresource and load during onload of page.

Comment: That can also be done. My main goal, is an access to a data-set or API that have all the +4 digit zip-code(eg. xxxxx-xxxx) in the country(U.S). I found some data-set online, but they only have the 5-digit zip-code(xxxxx).